# Backquoted symbols, good or bad?

Tags: language-design, syntax

I'm designing a programming language which has three kinds of quoted entities: strings and characters as in C, and symbols (interned strings intended for use as lookup keys and such) which I consider one of the most endearing features of Lisp. Currently I have the following syntax for these:

```
"*" // String
'*' // Character
`*` // Symbol
```

which I quite like, but has a couple of potential problems:

1. I'm told that on some keyboard layouts, backquote is a nuisance to type.
2. Backquote and ' are not the most visually distinct of characters, and I have a few times found myself typing ' when I meant backquote. On my setup this is not a problem because I have UltraEdit syntax highlighting set up to show backquoted symbols in green so the mistake is instantly apparent, but of course I can't provide syntax highlighting for most of the editors people use, so at least in the early days most users won't have the benefit of that kind of special coloring.

So, given these potential problems, I'd like to get some feedback on which option people consider preferable:

1. Keep the syntax the way I have it now.
2. Swap backquote and ', so that ' is used for symbols and backquote is used for character constants.
3. Use ' for symbols, @"*" for character constants (in e.g. the Linux kernel code, character constants are something like thirty times rarer than string constants, so it's arguably okay to give them slightly more verbose syntax) and backquote for something else, perhaps raw (most escape codes not interpreted) strings.
4. Use ' for symbols, @"*" for character constants and forswear the use of backquote entirely.

Comment: You might want to study Python's approach to this problem before inventing something that's too complex.

Comment: From what I've seen, Python uses both single and double quotes for strings, and doesn't have a separate notion of either characters or symbols; am I missing something?

Comment: Python does not have a need for character as a separate type.  **All** strings are "interned".  It's much simpler than the approach you're outlining.  Keep reading.

Comment: Indeed, Python doesn't have the need for character as a separate type or for uninterned strings, but I do need these things for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: "I do need these things".  You're missing the point.  You may not actually **need** the complexity you're designing.  It's very difficult to justify non-interned strings and a separate character type.

Comment: Well, character constants at least for comparing with the return values of C I/O functions, e.g. the return value of `getchar` is a small integer not a string object. And one of my objectives is to allow manual control of memory management (systems programming etc.), hence not all strings need be interned... Though thinking about it, is it necessary to have uninterned string _constants_? Maybe not so much.

Comment: "C I/O functions"  "manual control of memory management".  Sounds like you're re-inventing C.  Are you sure all the syntax you're inventing is **necessary**?

Comment: Who cares if it is necessary or not. Lisp decided it was (ahem) necessary for such functionality, so why can't the OP? Fun fact: Mike Tyson invented Lisp.

Comment: Just confirming, the backquote is very hard to type on a Swedish keyboard. It's a three way chord, shift+key left of backspace. Release all keys. Press space. One of the reasons I no longer use a Swedish layout any more.

Comment: @S.Lott can you point to a reference that all strings are interned in Python? All I see is that identifiers in programs and certain other "name-like" strings are.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object.  "Some languages do this automatically: for example, Python automatically interns short strings".  This probably varies by implementation.

Comment: @rwallace: *"I'm told that on some keyboard layouts, backquote is a nuisance to type."*... Especially for touch-typists. on a regular QWERTY keyboard that key is one of the worst offender. There's nothing worse than that, besides maybe the default overreliance of *vi* on the ESC key.  But, yup, backquote is horrible left-pinky strectching and that is definitely RSI-inducing.  Probably my only gripe about Clojure ; )  Now, of course, should it prove to be too much RSI-inducing I'd simply add another keybinding producing the backquote without needing to distort my left-pinky ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the potential confusion is a serious problem.  If you already find yourself confusing backquote and single-quote, think how many future code writers and readers will make the same mistake.

Many languages that use backquotes as special syntax seem to reserve them for comparatively rare usage.  I could speculate why, but if you expect symbols to get heavy usage, you could take this as a cue to use some other syntax.

So, for the multiple choice bonus question, I would prefer #3 or #4 over #1 or #2, for anti-confusion reasons.  You can keep backquotes in reserve for when you need an extra-special quotelike operator...

Comment: I agree. I've concluded S.Lott is right, I don't need so many options, because it's fine for all string constants to be interned, so I'll just use single quotes for interned strings/symbols.

Answer (score 3):

If you're introducing a new concept (symbols) into a familiar syntax, why not introduce new notation along with it? For example, within the rules of your lexer you could use a single lead-in character for a simple symbol name:

```
$symbol
$this_could_also_be_a_symbol_name
```

For arbitrarily named symbols, a `symbol("$ymbol w1th 4rbitrary n4m3")` compile-time construct could provide the needed flexibility. It might even be useful to have a function that constructs symbols at runtime, depending on the semantics of your language.

It occurs to me that [Ruby does almost exactly this using `:`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html):

```
:symbol
:this_could_also_be_a_symbol_name
:'$ymbol w1th 4rbitrary n4m3'
```

Comment: `$` is a poor choice as well, because it’s inconvenient to type on many northern and eastern European keyboard layouts. Besides, `:` looks better anyway.

Comment: To be honest most non-QWERTY layouts hardly make any sense when it comes to programming.  I'm in Europe but my keyboard is definitely QWERTY... (and I do "compose" the "euro characters with diacritical marks" when I do need them).

Answer (score 0):

Smalltalk also has a distinction between the three things, and uses this syntax:

```
'strings are in single quotes'
"comments are in double quotes. Yes, comments!"
$a "is the character a, dollar-sign prefixes characters"
#symbol "is a symbol, prefixed by a hash"
```

Aside from the potential difficulty of getting at some symbols (sorry Euro-folks!) it does have the unconventional but pleasant syntax of using single-quotes for strings, since it doesn't (on an American keyboard) require a shift-key press to get at and you type a lot more strings than characters (comments using the double-quote is a bit odd, but arguably people put up with longer key strokes for comments since they are typed in a different mindset than code.)

There are really several ways you can handle it, but keep in mind the rarity and use cases for each type.  Strings will get used a lot, and should have the easiest syntax.  Characters are rarer to use.  Symbol-usage will depend on how much meta-programming your language allows or requires.

You can also do some trickery at compile-time, depending on how much type-checking you've got you might be able to convert a single-character string to a char or a char to a single-character string as needed with implicit casting.  In most high-level languages, the needs to directly utilize an actual `char` type are fairly uncommon.

Another option is to use tagged strings. C#, for example, has `"regular strings"` and `@"non-escaping strings that ignore things like \n"`.  The D language uses `r"this is a string"` for the same purpose.  Those are very good for symbol heavy strings like regexps or directory names.  You could use `c"A"` for characters and `s"symbol"` for symbols.  Letters as operators is tricky business, but it makes for a very easy mnemonic for the programmer, and shouldn't be hard to lex since a string literal would never directly follow a symbol without whitespaces in most languages.

Comment: I never found shifted quotes difficult on any keyboard layout, whether to the right of semicolon or on the "2" key.  String literals, however, would strike me as being more likely to need apostrophes inside than quotation marks.  Personally, I liked the Vax BASIC approach of allowing either single or double quotes to be used for strings, thus allowing either "There can't be a problem here" or 'He said "Hi"'.

Answer (score -1):

Since an instance of the char type is only one character long, do you really need to enclose it in matching marks?  If you bracket symbols in apostrophes, you can use only a single backquote to precede a char.  If the user mixes them up, large syntax error messages follow, like when a C programmer forgets a closing brace.